# Making a new adjective

Tags: sentence-construction, adjectives

> I have just finished reading a book. It was so boring that sometimes I fell asleep. I will never buy such "**put-to-sleep**" books like that anymore.

I would like to know if the adjective *put-to-sleep* makes sense, and if the sentence above is correct.

Comment: Using both "such" beforehand and "like that" afterwards is a little redundant, so you might consider eliminating one or the other.

Comment: Personally, I'm a fan of "soporific", but "tranquilizing" is more common, not to mention "sedative" which doesn't get much use as an adjective, but would be perfectly fine as well.

Comment: Yes Tyler, you're right. "Like that" is redundant. I'll delete it. Thank you.

Comment: As long as you're still working on it, I might also suggest choosing between "I will never buy such **a**... book **again**" and "**I never** buy such... books anymore" constructions, depending on the desired timeframe and generality (I recommend the former). You currently have a mix of the two that, while perfectly intelligible (and technically correct), sounds slightly out of tune.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The word we would use in this context would be *boring*. The previous sentence has already informed the reader that the book was so bad it almost put them to sleep; that doesn't need to be repeated (plus we don't really have a common word that describes that.) I'd write your sentence like this:

> I will never buy such a boring book again.

If you really wanted a word that explicitly calls out the fact that it put you to sleep several times, you could try this:

> I will never buy such a sleep-inducing book again.

This would be understood, though I'd expect *boring* to be much more common.

Comment: Thanks Wendi. I know that the word boring is much more common. I just wanted an ironic adjective that conveyed better my meaning.

Comment: @jeysmith *Sleep-inducing* will work well if humor is your goal :) Glad to help!